# Use of “might” to talk about the possible events in the future

Tags: modal-verbs, future-time

> She *might have come*/ *might be coming* over this evening, so can you tidy the house up a bit?

Do these phrases "might have come" and "might be coming" represent the same meaning for the future event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She might come...

> She might be coming

This refers to a possible future event. There is little difference between "come" and "be coming"

---

> She might have come

This refers to a possible past event.  It is possible that she came earlier today. It doesn't say anything about the future.

Comment: In British English (and I suspect this may be true of other variants) we can use 'might' to express surprise or anger about past actions that we think people should have done, but did not. You cancelled your wedding when I had booked a flight from Australia? You might have told me!